# Return XML cell data in XML query with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 that contains some customer data. One of the columns in the table contains license data that is stored as XML. The type of the cell is `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Is it possible to use `FOR XML` (or some other method) so that when the data is returned the XML from the license data is included as XML rather than a formatted string?

If I simply use FOR XML RAW, then the result is:

```
<Customers id="1" CustomerName="FirstCustomer" 
           LicenseData="&lt;license customerid=&quot;1&quot;&gt;...More data here...&lt;/license&gt;" />
```

What I would liket to get is:

```
<Customers id="1" CustomerName="FirstCustomer">
    <license customerid="1">
        ...More data here...
    </license>
</Customers>
```

Is there any way to make that happen?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If your license data really always is XML - **store it as `XML`** !

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I wasn't the designer of this specific table, I'm just trying to work with it. I might be able to change the data type to XML, but I have to go through some other code to make sure I'm not breaking anything else first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XML is a valid fragment then you can simply [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it to XML.

```
SELECT CAST(MyColumn as XML) as MyXml
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answer.  It does exactly what I need.  In this case, I actually accepted Rhys Jones' answer because I don't need to create a temp table to get the results, just query and cast.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @temp table (id int, customername nvarchar(128), data nvarchar(max))

insert into @temp
select 1, 'FirstCustomer', '<license customerid="1"><element id="2">data1</element><element id="3"/></license>'

select id, customername, cast(data as xml)
from @temp
for xml raw
```

And you'll get results like this:

```
<row id="1" customername="FirstCustomer">
  <license customerid="1">
    <element id="2">data1</element>
    <element id="3" />
  </license>
</row>
```